# Problem in upgrading Cuda 10.2 in Conda Environment

Tags: cuda, conda, ubuntu-18.04

I want to upgrade Cuda 10.1 to 10.2, but I am not root user as I am using a client account.

so my only option seems to use conda.
I used this command `conda install cudatoolkit=10.2.89` and it installed the packages.

Now if i use again, it indicates that it is already installed. but when i check with

nvcc --version

it says `10.1` is installed.

Here is a screenshot of the problem. I need to install Pytorch but unable to go forward.

[image]

Comment: The actual CUDA version is determined by the driver and that must be installed by a root user.

Comment: Conda doesn't install nvcc. Their "cuda-toolkit" package is just runtime libraries. You clearly have a full CUDA 10.1 installation somewhere as well. And @merv: no the driver has nothing to do with any of this

Comment: so what is the purpose of the cuda toolkit? just to show off?  its around 500MB toolkit.

Comment: What conda distributes is what is required to run the CUDA accelerated python libraries they support. What nvidia distributes is everything that conda installs, plus all the tools you need to actual develop, compile and debug code on the GPU

Comment: @talonmies so the duplicate is incorrect? Should I reopen?